# Make free shipping available on specific days of the week in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm looking for a way to give free shipping on all orders based on weekday of the order. So if someone places an order (let's say on Monday) it will give him free shipping no matter what type of order quantity/amount/etc.

I've tried to hook up something from different other tutorials but I can't seem to get the part where I change the free_shipping limit + not sure it works since it's incomplete.

```
function free_shipping_day( $rates, $package ) {

// valid days
$valid_days = array('Mon');

// current day
$today = date ( 'D' );

// check if it's valid day
if( in_array($today, $valid_day) ){
    // clear other shipping methods allow only free
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;

        }

    }

    // set free_shipping limit to 0


    // show notice
    wc_add_notice( __( "Shipping is free today!" ), 'notice');
}
}

add_action('woocommerce_package_rates', 'free_shipping_day');
```

Any help is very appreciated since I'm kind of stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make free shipping **available** on specific days of the week, it requires a **different hook** to **bypass** the free shipping limitations *(if they exist)*.

We use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with **"w"** parameter that gives an integer from **`0`** (Sunday) to **`6`** (Saturday):

```
// Enable free shipping on specific days of the week
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'enable_free_shipping_for_specific_week_days', 10, 3 );
function enable_free_shipping_for_specific_week_days( $is_available, $package, $shipping_method ) {
    // Free shipping is available on mondays and wednesdays for example
    if( in_array( date('w'), [ 1, 3 ] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return $is_available;
}
```

To hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available, you can use additionally the following:

```
// Hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_other_shipping_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available', 100, 2 );
function hide_other_shipping_methods_when_free_shipping_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    $free = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I want to also reduce the free shipping limit to 0 for that day, so it will give free shipping to any order.

Comment: Indeed, it sets free shipping true, interesting approach, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function enable_free_shipping_for_days( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    // valid days
    $valid_days = array('Mon');
    if( !in_array( date('D'), $valid_days ) ) return $rates;

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) continue;
        $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
    }
    if( $free ) wc_add_notice( __( "Shipping is free today!" ), 'notice');
    return ( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'enable_free_shipping_for_days', 99 );
```

Comment: It's a tested code. Do you have passed 'Wed' in array. If so then just refresh cart fragments once by update cart or remove item from cart. And check.

Comment: Sorry, it won't work, added the code in my functions of the parent theme, cleared caches, tried incognito, but no succes (used this: $valid_days = array('Thu');)